# Advanced usage of add_index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Ruby on Rails project I have migration that creates case insensitive index for string column.

```
class AddCeCodeToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :ce_code, :string

    execute <<-SQL
      CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_users_on_lower_ce_code_index
        ON users USING btree (lower(ce_code));
    SQL
  end
end
```

This works as expected but I want to know is there any way to do the same using rails built_in add_index method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For mysql try:

```
add_index "users", "lower(ce_code)", name: "index_users_on_lower_ce_code"
```

For PG try:

install gem ["schema_plus_pg_indexes"](https://github.com/SchemaPlus/schema_plus_pg_indexes)

```
t.index expression: "lower(ce_code)", name: "index_users_on_lower_ce_code"
```

Answer (score 5):

ActiveRecord 5.2 or greater supports indexing on `lower(field)`:

```
class AddEmailInsensitiveIndex < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    change_table :users do |t|
      t.index "lower(email)", name: "index_users_on_lower_case_email"
    end
  end
end
```

https://www.joshmcarthur.com/til/2019/10/15/fancy-postgres-indexes-with-activerecord.html